# How does bash quoting work with curly brace {} expansion?

Tags: bash, quoting

I'm trying to write a bash script to reproduce a failing test.

The original command was (say we are testing echo)

```
echo aa @p{0,1}=port bb
```

which prints:

```
aa @p0=port @p1=port bb
```

I've got the arguments in a variable

```
TESTCASE='aa @p{0,1}=port bb'
```

so I build the command line

```
CMD='echo '${TESTCASE}
```

and then execute it

```
${CMD}
```

and I get:

```
aa @p{0,1}=port bb
```

i.e. the curly braces don't expand like they would on the command line

What is going on and how do I fix it?

Comment: `eval $CMD` will get you what you want

Comment: There is no `@` operator in `bash`.

Comment: More on `brace expansion`, here http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace

Comment: @chepner There is with extglob?

Comment: brace expansions happen *before* variable substitution. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions -- use chepner's answer.

Comment: @123 Touché :) This isn't it, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from comments by Aserre and glenn jackman, combined:

Brace expansions happen before variable substitution: 
see [gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions)

```
eval $CMD
```

will get you what you want

Comment: Do *not* use `eval` just to get brace expansion.

Comment: Why not? It seems to do exactly what I want, which is to execute the command as if I had typed it in.

Answer (score 7):

Use an array to store multiple arguments, not a regular parameter. Brace expansion will be applied to the strings inside the parentheses before setting the value of the array parameter.

```
test_case=( aa @p{0,1}=port bb )
```

Use a function to store code, not a regular parameters.

```
cmd () {
    echo "${test_case[@]}"
}
```